# Application architecture in scope of configuration, viewsets and dockable windows

Tags: design-patterns, configuration, architecture, navigation, docking

**Description**

I have an *C#*/*WPF* application that uses *MVVM* pattern and *PRISM*. My app has viewsets, dockable single- and multi-instance windows. There are user settings (window size, position), workspace settings (viewsets, docking layout, column sizes, python scripts, list of entries in watch windows, logging intervals per entry, etc.) and project settings (a hierarchical list of entries with additional properties) all stored as *XML* files using custom serializers. App is made in a very generic manner, modules 'doesn't know' about each other, partially *PRISM* service locator is used and partially *DI*, *PRISM* events are tuned down to absolute minimum.

**Issue**

I will now consider only workspace settings - they are managed by *ConfigurationManager*. *ViewSetManager* is responsible for managing viewsets and *DockingManager* is responsible for serializing/deserializing window layout for selected viewset. There is additional *NavigationManager* that provides a wrapper for *PRISM* regarding getting a list of views/viewmodels and navigating considering the fact that there are multiple viewsets.

Currently *ConfigurationManager* exposes *Loading*, *Loaded*, *Saving*, *Saved* events. To these events is subscribed *ViesetManager* (in order to recreate viewsets, when new configuration is loaded) and *DockingManager* (to perform required serializations).

*ViewSetManager* has *ViewSetChanged* event. To that event is subscribed *ConfigurationManager* (to know when viewset has been added/removed/changed by user) and *DockingManager* (to perform required serializations). It's worth noting that *ViewSetManager* is an entity instantiated inside *ConfigurationManager*.

As you can see, this approach is quite complicated and error prone.

**Question**

1. Who's responsibility is to manage all the connection between *ConfigurationManager*, *ViewSetManager*, *DockingManager*?

   - Should it be done with events or maybe by additional mediator or perhaps *ShellViewModel*?
   - How it should be ideally done?
2. Should *ConfigurationManager* instantiate any complex objects that manage application or should simply provide basic properties to be used by other parts of the app?

**Bonus Question**

3. Should *ConfigurationManager* be a single entity responsible for serialization/deserialization, watching file and providing settings or it should be divided into two separate entities - one responsible for file operations and one for settings provisioning?

**Possible solutions**

I am redesigning mentioned architecture. In a new approach an area that will display all the views is called *ViewSetRegion* - it manages viewsets and when new *DockingControl* is added (perhaps by *ViewSetManager*) it creates new dynamic *DockingRegions*, which can be populated with views from different part of the app. I believe this is quite clean design, however I am unsure how to connect this part of the application with *ConfigurationManager*.

**Final note**

If you could provide me at least answers to those questions or any meaningful articles on this topic or an actual application design I would be grateful :)